# float:left question

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have stuff like:

```
<div id="div1">
<div style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

And the div1 appears to have 0x0 size instead of 100x100. Why?

Comment: Perhaps you need to clear your float.  Try `<br style="clear: both;" />` inside `"div1"` after the other DIV.

Comment: @Orbling Why not just `overflow:auto` on the #div1 element?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: It is good practice to clear floats in general.

Comment: @Orbling I don't think that using a dedicated HTML element just to clear a float is a good practice, do you?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Depends on the location.

Comment: @Orbling I don't follow you. In what scenario is it a good solution?

Comment: @Šime Vidas, @Orbling: Sometimes if I find an element that logically "clears" a set of floated boxes before it (if you get what I mean), I may give it `clear` styles. As an example, I often tell my page footers `clear: both`, and it works really well.

Comment: @BoltClock @Orbling Yes, that is a fine practice. But that does not address my point, which is: `<br style="clear:both">` - a dedicated HTML element which does not introduce any new content into the document and which whole purpose is to clear floats. I don't think that using such an element is a good practice (ever). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Not good practice at all. Just because of the `style` attribute if not anything else.

Answer (score 7):

`#div1` isn't floated itself, so it doesn't appear to contain the inner `div`. Floating takes an element out of [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow), so `#div1` sort of isn't aware of its child anymore.

To make it do so, you need to float `#div1` too, or give it `overflow: hidden` to make it contain its inner `div`'s float (or use a clearfix).

Comment: @Bogdan0x400: A clearfix is a tag you use that doesn't do anything other than clear a float. For example `<br style="clear: both" />` or `<div style="clear: both"></div>`

Answer (score 3):

Clear the float:

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/

Update:

A List Apart has a good article on this type of thing:  http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

From the article:

> ...floated elements are originally calculated in the normal flow and then removed, the #container element doesn’t consider it within its bounds and therefore acts as if it isn’t even there..

Answer (score 2):

Just set

```
#div1{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or add

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

just before #div1 closing tag.